# Zsh autocomplete if only one suggestion

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

It seems like in Zsh, if you're using `menucomplete`, even if there is only one completion suggestion, you still have to hit `tab` again in order to accept it. Is it possible to configure Zsh to use menu completion, but if there's only one completion, to accept it on the first `tab` press?

Here's the relevant lines from my `.zshrc`:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _list _oldlist _expand _complete _ignored _correct _approximate
zstyle ':completion:*' completions 1
zstyle ':completion:*' glob 1
zstyle ':completion:*' insert-unambiguous true
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ''
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{[:lower:]}={[:upper:]}' 'r:|[._-/]=* r:|=*' 'l:|=* r:|=*'
zstyle ':completion:*' max-errors 3
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=1
zstyle ':completion:*' original true
zstyle ':completion:*' select-prompt %SScrolling active: current selection at %p%s
zstyle ':completion:*' substitute 1
zstyle ':completion:*' verbose true
zstyle :compinstall filename '/Users/aaronstacy/.zshrc'

autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

And the output of `setopt`:

```
§ setopt                                     
combiningchars
interactive
login
monitor
promptsubst
shinstdin
zle
```

Comment: Maybe share output of `setopt` too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand _complete _list _oldlist`

If you change the order of `_complete` further to the left (before `_list` and `_oldlist`), the completion will happen before the list.

And when you type `vim long<TAB>` it expands fully without list to `vim_longfilename`

Comment: this just makes my day thank you

Comment: According to [documentation](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html) `_expand` should be before `_complete`.

> Note also this completer should be called before the _complete completer function

Comment: @Tun thanks for the correction. Can you quote where it says so? I tried searching but couldn't find it.

Comment: @dza find with "Note also this completer should be called before the _complete" phrase. It is around the middle of the page under `_expand` completer.

Comment: @Tun ty, just edited answer.